# What drive the natural result order for an unordered MySQL request

Tags: mysql, database

How does mysql return lines when there is no ORDER BY in the request?

What drives the natural order?

There can obviously be many different queries but let's say a simple

`select column from table where date < NOW()`

Comment: Oftentimes it's the order in which the records are stored on disk, but it isn't necessarily so.

Answer (score 3):

There is no natural predictable order when you don't specify one.

Comment: how come it can always be random then?

Comment: You would have to be the developer of the DB engine to know how the software grabs the records.

Comment: @NicolasManzini random order is a special case of unspecified order.

Comment: For a single table it would probably be ordered by the clustered index (i.e. how the data is physically arranged) but as stated, I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: @usr okay, if its not random what is the answer for unspecified order

Comment: @NicolasManzini MySQL would normally return the rows in the order it finds them, when there is no order by. The order it finds the rows depends on too many things - e.g. the location in the data structure where the row is stored, which depends on the order which rows were inserted or deleted in - which again depends on many low level allocation algorithms. Then there's quite a few abnormal or uncommon cases. The short version is that you can't really know or predict the order.

Comment: @NicolasManzini you are insisting on the assumption that there *is* a natural order. There is none. Not even for a specific query on a specific software version. You cannot make any assumptions about the order at all.

Comment: will the last inserted row be fetched first for example?

Comment: @NicolasManzini It could. But there is no guarantee that it will.

Comment: @NicolasManzini maybe it helps you to take the other side. Assume that the engine randomizes the order of rows returned. How would you answer you own question then?

Comment: :) then how does mysql randomize the returned lines? This question is more about curiosity then a solution in case.

Comment: The results are not randomized on purpose. You just can't predict the order.

Comment: @NicolasManzini Place 10 coins on in row on a table. Then delete one (remove it). Then add two coins, The first one might fit where you just removed a coin. The other of the two coins you add to the right of all your coins. Repeat this process for a while where you add and remove coins. Then you want to browse through all the coins (e.g. select * from ... ) by going through them left to right. What order are the coins in when you do that ? It'll appear pretty random, and depend on the history you have by removing/adding coins. This is a simplified description of what a DB engine would do.

Answer (score 1):

Be very careful with this. For all SQL there is no *defined* implied order. Never count on this. Even if you see a specific behavior at a point in time, that could change in a future release or even with the adding of an index. If you are expecting an order and counting on it, the specify it explicitly.

Problem is that "natural order" of results is often affected completely or partly by the access plan the DB engine uses. For instance, if you do a group by FieldA there is a good chance (*not* a guarantee) that the results will come back in FieldA sequence. If you do a very simple select chances are the results will be in the sequence they are stored in the database, which may or may not be the order of the IDs or the primary key. IF you don't specify the order it is giving the DB engine the option to do whatever is most convenient for it at the time based on how it got the results. So really does become unpredictable and open to change.

Wish I could explain better, but trying to convey the real randomness of the process form an observer viewpoint.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am doing. I'm really wondering what drive the natural order of returned lines.

Comment: Added some to the original post. Really is hard to visualize and explain.

Answer (score 0):

If the query is using an index, it will prefer the ordering of that index.  Group by forces an ordering.  This is why combining group by and order can have a performance penalty.

In your case, if you have an index on date, it will probably order by that, hard to say how it handles tie breaks though.  For more information, as usual explain the query.

Of course there's a caveat to ordering on the index used as well.  If the index is on an autoincremented field and the data was added with prespecified ids, you may find it prefers the order the data was added in.